# ¿Cómo hacer lento un for?

Tags: java, array, java-swing, bucle-for

Estoy creando un programa que busca el camino más corto en un laberinto, utilizando Java Swing.
Tengo una matriz en dos dimensiones tanto lógica como gráfica de JLabels, que me sirven para pintar caminos y muros. Ya tengo toda la lógica de cuando un JLabel se comporta como muro, como camino o como corredor.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden observar, el corredor avanzo de una posición (x,y) de la matriz hacia otra diferente (xf,yf), y dibuja un camino del recorrido que realizo.
Para verificar que el camino este libre y no choque con algún muro (JLabels rojos) tengo un for que se encarga de recorrer la distancia ya predeterminada.

```
//Verfico que las posiciones finales no excedan el tamaño de la matriz
        if(posCol < 25 && posRow <25){
            labels2D[posRow][posCol].runner = false;
            int posRowf = posRow; //Posicion final del camino "y"
            int posColf = posCol; //Posicion final del camino "x"
            //Ahora tengo que avanzar hacia la derecha (por el momento)
            fr : for(int col = posCol; col<25; col++){
                //Verifico que la casilla del camino no sea un bloque
                if(labels2D[posRow][col].block == false){
                    //Si no es un bloque que dibuje una carretera
                    //Y que asigne la posicion final en esa posición
                    //Para luego hacer saltar al corredor
                    labels2D[posRow][col].changeColor(Color.GRAY);
                    labels2D[posRow][col].setText("-");
                    posRowf = posRow;
                    posColf = col;
                }else{
                    break fr;
                }
            }
            labels2D[posRowf][posColf].runner = true;
            labels2D[posRowf][posColf].changeColor(Color.GREEN);
            labels2D[posRowf][posColf].setText("");
        }
```

**MI PROBLEMA**
Necesito que en cada iteración del for haga una especie de "pausa" para que pinte los componentes y se logre ver un tipo de "animación de movimiento".

Ya intente usando:

```
private void delay(long ms){
    try {
        Thread.sleep(ms);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
}
```

Y llamando al método delay() dentro del for, sin embargo note que si hace la pausa en cada iteración pero por alguna razón no pinta los JLabels uno a uno, si no lo hace de golpe al finalizar todo el for.

Comment: No estoy muy seguro pero prueba con `Thread.yield()`

Comment: Ahora mismo voy a intentar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Después de varios meses no pude resolver el problema, la solución es que al usar el hilo principal no se puede pausar los componentes de Swing así que hay dos alternativas para resolver el problema.

1. Realizando el proceso de Thread.sleep() en otro hilo distinto al principal (donde se encuentra corriendo los componentes de Swing.
2. Utilizar la clase javax.swing.Timer que es justamente para conseguir este tipo de animaciones o pausas en componentes Swing.

Answer (score 1):

por lo que veo y entiendo (que es poco) estas cambiando los colores de los labels fuera del bucle, en otras palabras estas pintando despues de que el corredor ya hizo todo el recorrido y llego a su meta...
por eso es que al usar el metodo delay(long) se para pero pinta todo al final,
prueba repintando (cambiando los colores de los labels) dentro del bucle,
osea que cada vuelta del bucle repinte los labels segun la informacion que tienes hasta el momento.

Con eso y el metodo delay(long) conseguiras el efecto que buscas.

Comment: Pero dentro del for estoy llamando al metodo changeColor() el cual realiza la tarea de cambiar el color un JLabel.